# What is wmsAuthSign token?

Tags: authentication, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I saw wmsAuthSign token in query params of some hls or stream urls. I need to know what is this exactly? this is about a standard or a softwatre or what?

Answer (score 0):

wmsAuthSign is just a parameter that can be added to any streamable URL to provide token-based authorization. It is to prevent Hot-linking (or hotlinking), which is a process of re-streaming of the streaming media.

It works by checking each incoming connection signature against original published signature. The media would only play if they match.